# Sort using dynamic LINQ on a complex object

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, dynamic-linq

I have a list of Objects on which I use dynamic LINQ to perform sorting.

The object is like this,

```
public class SampleDTO
    {
        public string Vendor { get; set;}
        public string Invoice { get; set; }
         ..
         ..

}
```

And I use Dynamic Linq library to sort this,

```
var list= new List<SampleDTO>();
list.OrderBy("Vendor");
```

This works fine if I pass a sort key with a valid property name of the list ( e.g. Vendor )

The problem is, how to do this for a complex object.

Assume I have a another object which is a property of the SampleDTO

```
public class SampleDTO
    {
        public string Vendor { get; set;}
        public string Invoice { get; set; }
        public OtherDTO OtherDTO{get;set; }
         ..

}

public class OtherDTO 
{
        public string LineId{ get; set;}
        ..


}
```

And if I want to make the sorting dynamic enough so that I should be able to sort from a direct property of the SampleDTO or on a property of a OtherDTO ( e.g need to sort on OtherDTO.LineId )

What are the possible ways of achieving this?

/BB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
list.OrderBy("OtherDTO.LineId");
```

Comment: tkx, just took time to test it out

Comment: Sometimes the solution is so obvious that you don't see it :-)

Comment: How to achieve the above dynamically -- passing Sort column at run time.. ??

Answer (score 4):

why not use the lamba syntax.

`list.OrderBy(sample => sample.OtherDto.LineId);`

This has the advantage of not being reliant on hard coded strings

Comment: I guess there is a good reason for the OP to use dynamic LINQ in the first place.

Comment: because the column i need to do sorting on is not just the orderlineId, it can be someother column as well, that is why im using dynamic linq in the first place.